# Angularjs - loading bar hide page overlay

Tags: angularjs

Helo I used [this loadingbar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar). I need the page to overlay when sending requests. But div for overlay is still visible after loading is ended.
Here is my code:

```
    angular.module('app', ["angular-loading-bar"])
    .config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function (cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.parentSelector = '#loading-bar-container';
    }])
#loading-bar-container {
    pointer-events: all;
    z-index: 99999;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: wait;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

I need hide `#loading-bar-container` after loading is over. do you have any ideas how to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Where are you using the loader bar?

Comment: this lib is so small that it's much easier for you to put breakpoint into "response" interceptor code there to check why `setComplete()` is not called. wild guess: you may have some background requests sent by some 3rd party component. wild guess #2: I'm not sure if loadingbar correctly behaves once request has been canceled(if cancelling does not trigged `response` interceptors - loadingbar will not disappear)

Comment: @G_S and why not? :) it's easy way to visualize some networking activity is running in background.

Comment: I didnt knew .config( code is used for interceptors

Comment: Thank you for your comments. If you think that problem is in loading bar component, which another component you would recommend me?

Comment: @bluray just debug that. don't try to guess. it's really possible there is an issue related to your own code. I use cfpLoadingBar in several projects and everything is fine.

Comment: @skyboyer And you could show me your code? do you use the same principle as me? Thus overlay whole page using `parentSelector`?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question. So loading bar itself is hidden. But container you have customized is not. And container's background is still visible, right?

Comment: if yes you may just listen for event that it's broadcasting: `$rootScope.$broadcast('cfpLoadingBar:completed');`

Comment: also what is the point to style container instead of loading bar itself? is it just to apply "cursor: wait" to mouse pointer? it would be achieved much easier with adding some special class to <body> on "cfpLoadingBar:loading" and remove that class on "cfpLoadingBar:completed"

Comment: Please show me on example how to do it. I dont use cfpLoadingBar:completed. I use onlycfpLoadingBar.parentSelector property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166188/discussion-between-skyboyer-and-bluray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initially I misunderstood the question. So it's about hiding/showing container used for loading bar. Not about hiding/showing angular-loading-bar itself. So it could be done next way:

```
someModule.directive('loadingBarContainer', function ($rootScope) { 
    return { 
        restrict: 'A', 
        link: bindVisibilityToEvents 
    }; 

    function linkVisibilityToEvents($scope, $element) { 
        $rootScope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:loading', function () { 
            $element.show(); 
        });  
        $rootScope.$on('completed', function () { 
            $element.hide(); 
        }); 
    } 
})
```

And somewhere in your template:

```
<div id="loading-bar-container" loading-bar-container />
```

Also I believe it's more convenient to create different directive named say 'backdrop' and hide/show this  element styled with

```
backdrop {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: wait; 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So blocking UI and visualizing HTTP activity would be less coupled.